# Storing a hex string in php

Tags: php

Php newbie here. Trying to have a fixed key in my code. How do I do this?

In C for example I do this --

```
unsigned char key[] = { 0x3f, 0xee, 0x40, 0x93, 0x2f, 0xca, 0x7b, 0xdf, 0x9f, 0x04, 0x23, 0x62, 0x9e, 0x33, 0x98, 0x4f };
```

How do I do this php?  I know I have not completely understood the string concept in php but there is no concept of a byte array in php but how does php handle binary data? I mean specifically signed and unsigned characters.

I am guessing I could use the hex2bin somehow. Is this a correct representation of the above key in the C array?

```
$key = hex2bin('3fee40932fca7bdf9f0423629e33984f');
```

EDIT: What is the standard practice to represent a fixed key in code?

Comment: You'll get a string rather than actual binary. Try pack

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pack.php

Comment: Yes, your `hex2bin` gives you the equivalent PHP string.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but what is the common practice in php tp represent a key in code?

Comment: @theazureshow -- Can you show me how to use pack? I seem to not understand it properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PHP equivalent of your C code would be:

```
$key = array(
  0x3f,
  0xee,
  0x40,
  /* etc. */
);
```

PHP does things in a smart way: it handles your data types for you. There is no such thing as an "unsigned char". There's just an integer, which can easily become a string or a float if you use the right operators on it. The concept of unsigned numbers is foreign to PHP. They are all signed. If you wish your `0x80` to become `-128`, you'll need to look for a more PHP-ish solution ;).